# Tensorflow How to convert words(Strings) from a csv file to proper vectors

Tags: csv, machine-learning, nlp, tensorflow, deep-learning

Hi im trying to make a small classifier in tensorflow. I want to read data from a csv file and use it for my training phase, the problem is the content of my file looks something like this:

object,categorie
the blue balon,toy
a white plastic ship,toy
a big book,other
the wild cat,animal
a wet dolphin,animal
...

So i want to read the sentences and then convert them to vector for use in a tensorflow model. All the information i readed was about numerical data but no idea how to use data like this.

The turorials from the oficial site use numeric data, the best option so far has been use a dictionary but i think there should exist a better option.

Another option is to make my own method but could be imprecise.

Have someone any ideas how can i do that? 
an alternative for mi method or how can i process words in tensorflow?

Sorry if my english is not good.

**EDIT**

Try to convert sentences into multidimensional arrays but the results were not good, I estimate that the poor results are due to some statements can be short and others long, which affects the final free space on each array and this free space affects the results the probabilistic model. Any recommendation?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: So i was thinking in word2vec tool but need to have a c compiler and i dont want to make this small project even more complicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily, the solution is pretty simple using `pandas` module!

First, let's create a quick .csv file:

> example.csv:

```
"object","category"
"the blue balloon","toy"
"a white plastic ship","toy"
"a big book","other"
"the wild cat","animal"
"a wet dolphin","animal"
```

Now we can write our simple Python file:

> convert.py

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("example.csv")
print(data)

data = data.join(pd.get_dummies(data["category"]))
data = data.drop("category", axis=1)
print(data)
```

Finally, we can run our file and see our results!

```
$ python convert.py

                 object category
0      the blue balloon      toy
1  a white plastic ship      toy
2            a big book    other
3          the wild cat   animal
4         a wet dolphin   animal

                 object  animal  other  toy
0      the blue balloon     0.0    0.0  1.0
1  a white plastic ship     0.0    0.0  1.0
2            a big book     0.0    1.0  0.0
3          the wild cat     1.0    0.0  0.0
4         a wet dolphin     1.0    0.0  0.0
```

Comment: Thanks for you help! the thing is i need to convert the object column in valid data for tensor flow, maybe thats question for other topic, have you an idea how to do that? until now i keep reading tutorials with numeric data but in my case de data is string type and i have no idea of how should i manipulate this type of data for a simple classifier. Again thanks for the help :)

Comment: Can you clarify your input and target? I am not sure if I correctly understand what you are trying to do!

Comment: My problem is I need to convert strings to vectors for use them in my tensorflow model, the strings can be of variable length so dont know exactly how to deal with string type.

Comment: @OctavioSoto Did you get this working? I have a similar use case to you i think with string objects of variable length.